# Getting skipped out of the loop without letting me type

Tags: python

So I made a very simple Auto-typer and want to be able to run it again or quit it.
All works perfectly fine but at the end the "ending = input()" doesnt let me type it just exits out of the programm. Any reason why?

```
import pyautogui
import time
import os


def clearConsole():
    command = 'clear'
    if os.name in ('nt', 'dos'):  # If Machine is running on Windows, use cls
        command = 'cls'
    os.system(command)

break_loop = 1

while break_loop <= 1:
    secs_inbetween_actions = float(input("""
Seconds between actions(should be float but int is also ok): """))
    no_of_lines = int(input("""
How many Lines do you want to write?(Only int): """))
    time_between_action = int(input("""
How long should the time between enter and writing be?: """))
    lines = ""
    print("""
Write your Text under this message (You have """ + str(no_of_lines) + """ line(s) to wite)
""")
    for i in range(no_of_lines):
        lines += input() + "\n"

    print("-------------------------------------")

    while time_between_action > 0:
        time_between_action = time_between_action - 1
        print('Time Left until writing -+==> ' + str(time_between_action))
        time.sleep(1)

    print("-------------------------------------")
    pyautogui.typewrite(lines, interval=secs_inbetween_actions)

    ending = input("If you want to use this aplication once again type 'y' + 'enter key' ,if not press the 'enter key': ")

    if ending == "y":
        break_loop = 1
        clearConsole()
    else:
        break_loop += 1
```

Comment: What do you think `pyautogui.typewrite()` does?

Comment: `typewrite()` types the line, so it's being taken as the answer to the `input()` function.

Comment: My previous comment was erroneous; I've answered mainly to clear it up, although @Barmar certainly wrote the answer here as a comment before I'd finished writing it as an answer

Comment: @Barmar ok that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather fun little problem.  It occurs, as @Barmar notes, because `pyautogui.typewrite()` is writing to the console for you.  I incorrectly thought that it was *not* happening when there was no delay between actions, which was a far more puzzling little problem.

In this case the solution is easy: add after your `typewrite()`:

```py
if lines:
    input()
```

To absorb what has just been typed for you.